# Merge two files in linux with different column

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have two files in linux, the first file has 4 columns and the second has 2 columns. I want to merge these files into a new file that has the first 3 columns from file 1 and the first column from file 2. I tried awk, but my data from file 2 was placed under file 1.

Comment: It will really help if you provide an example of your input files as well as a description of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 48):

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5}'
```

Comment: Use `awk '{print $1","$2","$3}'` for comma-separated values

Answer (score 10):

Not sure which columns you want from each file, but something like this should work:

```
paste <file1> <file2> | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5}'
```

The first three columns would be picked from `file1`, and the fourth skipped, then pick the first column from the second file.

Answer (score 2):

If the files have the same number of rows, you can do something like:

```
awk '{ getline v < "file2"; split( v, a ); print a[2], $1, $3 }' file1
```

to print colums 1 and 3 from file 1 and column 2 from file2.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can try this one without paste command:
awk '{print $1}{print $2}{print $3}' file1 >> mergedfile
awk '{print $2}' file2 >> mergedfile
```