# Update a csv file with Ansible

Tags: csv, ansible

I have a csv file(A) with 10 rows and 4 columns. I have another file(B) with 10 rows and 1 column. I need to merge these two files in such a way that a new file is created ( or even update A file itself) with 10 rows and 5 columns. i.e. The B file's column needs to be appended to the last column of A.

Comment: Since there is only one column in file B I assume the rows are in the correct order to just be appended at the end of file A?

Comment: Yes, how the column appending is done with ansible

Comment: Why specifically with Ansible and not using bash?

Comment: We have the requirement to do it via ansible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there isn't a built in way to do this with Ansible modules I would recommend using the [`shell` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) and looking at similar answers with [merging CSV columns with Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160145/merge-two-files-in-linux-with-different-column).

Comment: Thank you, I will use the shell module with the paste command.