# script that adds column of a file to another

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Say I have two files

```
name qty preemp.
----------------------------------
TASK1 05 10
TASK4 10 07
TASK3 13 21
```

and

```
name qty migration
----------------------------------
TASK5 09 11
TASK1 05 10
TASK4 10 07
TASK3 13 21
```

I want to merge them into one like this:

```
name qty preemp. migration
--------------------------------------------------
TASK5 09 - 11
TASK1 05 10 10
TASK4 10 07 07
TASK3 13 21 21
```

What command(s) would be best for this, I have been trying to use awk with no luck.

Comment: Hi, not sure if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160145/merge-two-files-in-linux-with-different-column

Comment: consider updating the question to include your `awk` attempts and the output they generated